# Writing to files from batch using adb not working

Tags: adb

I am trying to have an automatic batch file replace a file on my android device, it works when i type it in manualy but for some wierd reason it doesn't in the batch file.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
echo Do you want to change the file?
echo 1)Yes

set /p choice= 
if %choice%==1 goto :change


:change
cd c:/
cd Users
cd Aidan
cd Desktop
cd My folder
cd platform-tools
adb devices
adb shell < change_file.txt
```

Then i have a remote file to run the commands, this is needed to run multiple commands is adb shell from a batch file.

Here is my change_file.txt :

```
su
cd storage
cd sdcard0
rm test.txt
cat > test.txt
test 
test
12345 test
```

In the command window it shows that it executes the commands several times and all it does it delete the file not replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this one. Your `cat` listens for text, but... it keeps listening. You never signal the input termination, thus it doesn't create the file.

Instead of the following lines:

```
cat > test.txt
test
test
12345 test
```

use these:

```
cat << EOF > test.txt
test
test
12345 test
EOF
```

This will instruct `cat` to accept input until the **End Of File** is inserted, and will create your **test.txt** with the content of said input. Don't forget the **EOF** at the end of the input, or the behaviour will be the same as if you used your version of the script.